# convert array value to key

Tags: php, arrays

I am working in PHP.

I have one array. i need to create language array like  (`[CN] => Chinese`) this format.

My array response is given below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [language_name] => Chinese
            [language_code] => CN
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [language_name] => English
            [language_code] => EN
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [language_name] => Korea
            [language_code] => KO
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [language_name] => Vietnamese
            [language_code] => VN
        )

)
```

I need to convert this type of array

```
Array(
      [CN]=>Chinese
      [EN]=>English
      [KO]=>Korea
      [VN]=>Vietnamese
)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
<?php

$newArray = array();

foreach($yourArray as $key => $items) {
    $newArray[$items->language_code] = $items->language_name;
}

die('<pre>' . print_r($newArray, true) . '</pre>');
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's `foreach` :

```
function convert($array){
    $ret = array();

    foreach($array as $obj){
        $ret[$obj->language_code] = $obj->language_name;
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
foreach($objects as $object)
{
    $newArray[$object->language_code] = $object->language_name;
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine

```
foreach($objects as $object)
{
    $newArray[$object->language_code] = $object->language_name;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
echo "</pre>";
```